# Can not install/download APPS via Play Store to my Tablet ....how can i fix this?

Tags: installation, tablet, google-apps

Over the past 2 days, whenever I try to download/install an APP via the Play Store/Market app on my TABLET, the app thinks for a while and then displays this error message:

*Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account.*

But I am indeed signed into my Google account, and as seen if I open the menu in the Market app and click the "Accounts" button.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-authenticate on my tablet, too. I assume Google is trying to detect fake accounts used to push fake-apps into the top apps list.

May be in your case there is a conflict between the cached data and the actual store data.

You can try to clear the app cache of "Google Play-Store services" app and the Google Play-Store app.

Additionally you should check your Google account in "Settings" -> "Accounts". Manually perform a synchronization.